# Why would I bid for white in armageddon (in regular chess)?

Tags: tournament, statistics, time-control, armageddon

Related:

Regular chess: [Why would I bid for white in armageddon (in regular chess)?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41552/why-would-i-bid-for-white-in-armageddon-in-regular-chess)

Chess960: [Why would I bid for white in armageddon in chess960?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41551/why-would-i-bid-for-white-in-armageddon-in-chess960)

[Were there armageddons where white gets lower time or where you can bid for white?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41549/were-there-armageddons-where-white-gets-lower-time-or-where-you-can-bid-for-whit)

[Armageddon: Has anyone actually bid for white in chess (or chess960)?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41593/armageddon-has-anyone-actually-bid-for-white-in-chess-or-chess960)

---

Re 2023 Champions Chess Tour Airthings Masters

From [Gukesh Beats Former World Champion Kramnik 3 Times, Dominates Play-In](https://www.chess.com/news/view/gukesh-wins-cct-airthings-masters-play-in)

[image]

Here, [armageddon bidding](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41525/how-is-armageddon-in-chess-like-fair-cake-cutting-in-game-theory) is not for black but for your colour of choice! But black still gets draw odds of course.

**Question**: Can the first move advantage really be worth having to play for a win on lower time?

My guess: Well in chess, maybe... [In Chess960? Yeah right.](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41538/armageddon-does-should-white-have-a-lower-advantage-in-chess960-compared-to-c) But ok let's just restrict to chess, where there's theory. IF you can get a good deal on the bid like if you win with 9:59, then ok. Maybe theory will be a good way to compensate for draw odds? (Of course if the other person really wants black, then they're not gonna bid just 9:59.)

Comment: Players usually choose Black in armaggedon

Comment: @David There were such [bids where you were allowed to choose white](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41549/were-there-armageddons-where-white-gets-lower-time-or-where-you-can-bid-for-whit)? But yeah if you win the bid, then I hardly see a reason to pick white (especially in chess960), but maybe it depends on the bid and how the previous games went.

Comment: @David Right so [how usual](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41593/armageddon-has-anyone-actually-bid-for-white-in-chess-or-chess960) is usually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think of this case of Sergey Karjakin vs Robert Hess in the [2019 WFRCC 3rd qualifying round](https://www.frchess.com/news/vidit-claims-spot-in-quarterfinals) (ok it's from chess960, but not really specific to chess960 maybe) :

> At the end of this chaotic and potentially historic Knockout Qualifier, both finalists joined commentator GM Aman Hambleton to offer their thoughts. On Hess, Karjakin offered praise, "I decided to play with the black pieces (in Armageddon) because he was outplaying me with any color and I thought at least if the draw suits me at least I will have chances."

I think of a similar thing that justifies playing white. **Maybe I was not outplayed as white.** Like say I played 4 games with someone and won the 2 white games and lost the 2 black games. Then maybe I'd want white. But this is specific to chess, in particular to the openings I played as white in the 2 games and the opening I plan to play in armageddon. In chess960, I have no idea if my luck with white will continue in the next starting position.