# Semi-armageddon: Like armageddon but still has draws

Tags: tournament, world-championship, time-control, advantage, armageddon

I heard of [pie rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_rule), but I doubt this has ever been done in a FIDE tournament in the last, say, 50 years.

Essentially, it's like [cake-cutting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4623937/how-is-armageddon-in-chess-like-fair-cake-cutting-in-game-theory) but you're cutting the cake of evaluation based on starting position instead of the cake of time like armageddon. Like [you bid](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7962/which-side-has-the-advantage-in-an-armageddon-tiebreak-game/8269#8269) on the position instead of the time. The 1 difference though is that armageddon eliminates draws. (Well you can have draw odds in pie rule, but I highly doubt white has any decent shot here.)

What I envision is a version of armageddon that's simply pie rule but for time, in particular no elimination of draws. I'll call this *semi-armageddon*. To be explicit:

- Regular armageddon: Black has draw odds. Players bid for black. ([Usually.](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41552/why-would-i-bid-for-white-in-armageddon-in-regular-chess))
- Introducing semi-armageddon: Original game except players bid for white.

**Question**: Has this be done or considered? And please mention which part of the considerations, if any, explain what ultimately were or might have been some reasons why these weren't implemented. Eg It's too time consuming to have every pair of players in a swiss tournament bid for white.

---

Some motivations for doing this:

1. In the 2023 FIDE World Cup and as prepared to be done in the 2023 world chess championship, they have an alternative to armageddon called 'sudden death' where they play infinite blitz matches until there's a decisive result, but there's no compensation for whomever gets black first.
2. Round robins & swiss tournaments are often done single, not double like the candidates from 2013-2024 (or quadruple like the candidates before 1963). Even if they do single round robins with odd number of players so that there even amounts of white & black, it's still technically unfair at least in each individual game that one player just gets black for no compensation whatsoever, even if the overall tournament is arguably fair. Actually, the 2022 Sinquefield Cup was a single round robin, and [1 of the issues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBTouiKmOCg) Magnus Carlsen had with Hans Niemann was:

> I had the impression that he wasn’t tense or even fully concentrating on the game in critical positions, while outplaying me as black in a way I think only a handful of players can do.

3. Even just for regular amateur online playing on chess.com or lichess, players just get black for no compensation. This isn't [quite a problem](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37673/why-dont-these-statistics-disprove-whites-supposed-larger-practical-advanta) in chess960, but I heard in regular chess, there's a thing where players abort and offer rematch to get white.
4. In [c-squared podcast (csqpod) w/ Hikaru Nakamura, around 1:02:18](https://youtu.be/rc-GquDy3PU?t=3736), Hikaru tells Fabiano Caruana & Cristian Chirila that Hikaru wished they could keep tiebreakers in world chess championships classical somehow. Hikaru wanted, as I understand, classical sudden death, which I guess is a classical version of what happened in the 2023 World Cup. I believe this is extremely unfair because at least in blitz sudden death, white doesn't have that much advantage. But this can now work if they do classical semi-armageddon. They could do just [classical armageddon](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/44981/why-isnt-there-more-classical-armageddon-with-auction), but [in a later episode w/ Maxime Vachier-Lagrave, around 2:22 (it's a clip from the full episode)](https://youtu.be/B2Gi-6EgcfY?t=141), MVL & Fabi say they don't like 'super long armageddon's.'