# Balancing white advantage but still has draws

Tags: tournament, world-championship, time-control, advantage, armageddon

I heard of [pie rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_rule), but I doubt this has ever been done in a FIDE tournament in the last, say, 50 years.

Essentially, it's like [cake-cutting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4623937/how-is-armageddon-in-chess-like-fair-cake-cutting-in-game-theory) but you're cutting the cake of evaluation based on starting position instead of the cake of time like armageddon. Like [you bid](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7962/which-side-has-the-advantage-in-an-armageddon-tiebreak-game/8269#8269) on the position instead of the time. The 1 difference though is that armageddon eliminates draws. (Well you can have draw odds in pie rule, but I highly doubt white has any decent shot here.)

**Question**: What are other attempts besides pie rule  or in the other post [semi-armageddon](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/44980/semi-armageddon-like-armageddon-but-still-has-draws) where there are ways to balance out white's advantage in a single game *without* eliminating draws? And please mention which part of the considerations, if any, explain what ultimately were or might have been some reasons why these weren't implemented. Eg for [semi-armageddon](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/44980/semi-armageddon-like-armageddon-but-still-has-draws)It's too time consuming to have every pair of players in a swiss tournament bid for white.